# How do I assign an element of @ARGV to a $variable, then print it?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, argv, string-interpolation

It has been frequently asked in various ways, however, I am going to ask again because I do not fully comprehend the application of `@ARGV` and because I have not found an answer to this issue (or, more likely, I do not understand the answers and solutions already provided).

The question is, why is nothing being read from the command-line? Also, how do I decrypt the error message,

> Use of uninitialised value $name in concatenation (.) or string at ... ?

I understand that `@ARGV` is an array that stores command-line arguments (files). I also understand that it can be manipulated like any other array (bearing in mind index `$ARGV[0]` is not the same as the command-line feature of filename variable, `$0`). I understand that when in a while-loop, the diamond operator will automatically `shift` the first element of `@ARGV` as `$ARGV[ ]`, having read a line at input.

What I do not understand is how to assign an element of `@ARGV` to a scalar variable and then print the datum. For example (code concept taken from Learning Perl),

```
my $name = shift @ARGV;

while (<>) {
    print “The input was $name found at the start of $_\n”;
    exit;
}
```

As the code stands, `$name`’s output is blank; were I to omit `shift()`, `$name` would output `0`, as I believe it should, being in scalar context, but it does not answer the question of why input from the command-line is nor being accepted. Your insights will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If this is your entire program (with `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at its beginning) then when you run it _with an argument_, like `prog.pl hello`, it will wait for input since `<>` reads `STDIN` if no files are given to the program.  (Since you `shift`-ed from `@ARGV`, which only had `hello` word, there is nothing in it and so `<>` waits.) Then you hit enter and it runs the print statement, with `hello` in variable `$name`. (If you give the program nothing at start then `$name` is empty but you seem to know that.) I don't see why/how it behaves differently for you?

Comment: In a loop `while (<>)` whatever input is read from the terminal is assigned to `$_` -- and you don't print it, so there's no way to see it.  However, that still doesn't explain how you get `$name` to be empty (if you pass an argument to the program when you start it).    So something isn't right in your problem description?  Note, what is in `@ARGV` are taken to be filenames by `<>`, and those files are opened and read line by line.

Comment: Find Perl's special variables in [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar) page. Find brief explanations of error messages in [perldiag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag) page.

Comment: Great, so it's clarified, in particular with ikegami's answer :).  It's a good question, carefully written.  Note, what I mention above, that if you supply arguments to the script then when execution comes to `<>` those arguments are treated as files (unless they've been removed from `@ARGV` earlier), which are opened and read line by line.  That's very useful since you can use `while (<>)` to _either_ process `STDIN` line by line (prompting and waiting for input, or reading input "piped" into the program) _or_ to process files. Flexible :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`my $name = shift @ARGV;` does indeed assign the program's first argument. If you get `Use of uninitialised value $name in concatenation (.) or string at ...`, it's because you didn't provide any arguments to your program.

```
$ perl -we'my $name = shift(@ARGV); print "My name is $name.\n"'
Use of uninitialized value $name in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 1.
My name is .

$ perl -we'my $name = shift(@ARGV); print "My name is $name.\n"' ikegami
My name is ikegami.
```

There's absolutely no problem with using `<>` afterwards.

```
$ cat foo
foo1
foo2

$ cat bar
bar1
bar2

$ perl -we'
   print "(\@ARGV is now @ARGV)\n";
   my $prefix = shift(@ARGV);

   print "(\@ARGV is now @ARGV)\n";
   while (<>) {
      print "$prefix$_";
      print "(\@ARGV is now @ARGV)\n";
   }
' '>>>' foo bar
(@ARGV is now >>> foo bar)
(@ARGV is now foo bar)
>>>foo1
(@ARGV is now bar)
>>>foo2
(@ARGV is now bar)
>>>bar1
(@ARGV is now )
>>>bar2
(@ARGV is now )
```

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on the correctness of the script and my oversight of not supplying input at the command line, as the script was expecting. I am not familiar with your method of writing and running the script from the command line, but I'll do some reading around your examples.

Comment: What are the three angle brackets `>>>` used for?

Comment: The fact that I provided the program on the command line is irrelevant. Same would happen if the program was in a file. So just pretend `perl -we'...'` is `perl foo.pl` or `./foo.pl` /// That's the argument. Using a name didn't really make sense

Comment: @Den  When you run from the command-line `perl -e'...'` what comes in between `''` is treated as a Perl program and it is executed (that's `-e`).  Handy for quick tests (or perhaps even running out of bash scripts or such). Also, there are many convenient switches, for example `perl -ne'...' file` will open the `file` and go through it line by line applying the code in `''` (that's `-n`).  See [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun).  In the bash shell you can even spread it over multiple lines, so the program above can be copied and pasted into your shell and then hit enter to run it.

Comment: @Den  I've heard of it, never seen it.  Sorry for the bumpy start -- any programming language can overwhelm if things are just thrown in your face, and Perl in particular is a power tool. But one good point about it is that it should be feasible to pick up basics (_relatively_) "easily," so perhaps that book just didn't do a good job with that topic?

Comment: @Den  If that book is working for you altogether, great (I can't recommend or dispute it since I don't know it). If not, there sure are choices. A classic is "Learning Perl" (and then you also need material from at least "Intermediate Perl"), but i haven't seen new, greatly revised, editions (after the second).  I've seen bits and pieces from "Modern Perl," available for free from the author's website, and I liked what I saw.

Comment: @Den I suggest that we remove these comments (starting with mine on one-liners), since they are off-topic and can distract from the answer.  Let me know when you've seen them and are ready.  Enjoy your learning :)

Comment: @Den I'm not worried. Lots of good info in these comments